# Remove <p> element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This has been driving me nuts for a few days and i've tried multiple different ways of tackling it. But for some reason it won't remove the element. Can anyone shine some light?

My goal is to on click add the inputed markup then on click of 'remove' remove the whole element.

HTML Mark Up

```
    <div id="p_test">
    <p>
        <div class="input-file-container">
            <input class="input-file" id="my-file" type="file">
            <label tabindex="0" for="my-file" class="input-file-trigger">Select a file...</label>
        </div>
        <p class="file-return"></p>
    </p>
</div>

<button class="btn--add" id="addtest">
        Add
      </button>
```

Jquery

```
$(function() {
    var test = $('#p_test');
    var i = $('#p_test p').length + 1;

    $('#addtest').on('click', function() {
        $('<p><div class="input-file-container"><label for="p_test" class="input-file-trigger">Select a file...<input type="text" id="p_test" name="p_test_' + i +'" value=""class="input-file"></label><p class="file-return"></p><span class="remtest">Remove</span></div><p>').appendTo(test);
        i++;
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.remtest' function(e) {
        if (i > 2) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
    });
});
```

I've tried different methods, each method failing.

```
$(this).closest("p").remove();
```

and

```
$('.remtest').on('click', function() {
    if (i > 2) {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
  i--;
    }
});
```

```js
$(function() {
 var test = $('#p_test');
 var i = $('#p_test p').length + 1;

 $('#addtest').on('click', function() {
  $('<p><div class="input-file-container"><label for="p_test" class="input-file-trigger">Select a file...<input type="text" id="p_test" name="p_test_' + i +'" value=""class="input-file"></label><p class="file-return"></p><span class="remtest">Remove</span></div><p>').appendTo(test);
  i++;
 });

// $(this).closest("p").remove();


 // $('.remtest').on('click', function() {
 //  if (i > 2) {
 //   $(this).parents('p').remove();
  //     i--;
 //  }
 // });
 $('body').on('click', '.remtest', function(e) {
  if (i > 2) {
   $(this).parents('p').remove();
   i--;
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="p_test">
 <p>
  <div class="input-file-container">
   <input class="input-file" id="my-file" type="file">
   <label tabindex="0" for="my-file" class="input-file-trigger">Select a file...</label>
  </div>
  <p class="file-return"></p>
 </p>
</div>

<button class="btn--add" id="addtest">
        Add
</button>
```

Comment: You need to fix your broken HTML first of all. You can not nest `div` or additional paragraphs into `p` elements.

Comment: Which `<p>` did you want removed? There's 2 of them, and the inner `<p>` is invalid, if I recall a `<p>` cannot contain another `<p>`. Not only is it semantically poor I believe grammatically it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't dont `<p>` as a "container" for your code. I switched out your `<p>` with `<div class="container">` and now your code works.

**demo**

```
$('body').on('click', '.remtest', function(e) {
    if (i > 2) {
      $(this).closest('.container').remove();
      i--;
    }
});
```

Use `$(this).closest('.container').remove();` and not `$(this).parent('.container').remove();` to get the outer "container".

```js
$(function() {
  var test = $('#p_test');
  var i = $('#p_test .container').length + 1;

  $('#addtest').on('click', function() {
    $('<div class="container"><div class="input-file-container"><label for="p_test" class="input-file-trigger">Select a file...<input type="text" id="p_test" name="p_test_' + i + '" value=""class="input-file"></label><p class="file-return"></p><span class="remtest">Remove</span></div><div>').appendTo(test);
    i++;
  });
  $('body').on('click', '.remtest', function(e) {
    if (i > 2) {
      $(this).closest('.container').remove();
      i--;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="p_test">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="input-file-container">
      <input class="input-file" id="my-file" type="file">
      <label tabindex="0" for="my-file" class="input-file-trigger">Select a file...</label>
    </div>
    <p class="file-return"></p>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn--add" id="addtest">
        Add
</button>
```

Comment: @MatthewEgan Don't feel stupid, everyone has to learn, just happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.. you were trying to remove the wrong element

```js
$(function() {
 var test = $('#p_test');
 var i = $('#p_test p').length + 1;

 $('#addtest').on('click', function() {
  $('<p><div class="input-file-container"><label for="p_test" class="input-file-trigger">Select a file...<input type="text" id="p_test" name="p_test_' + i +'" value=""class="input-file"></label><p class="file-return"></p><span class="remtest">Remove</span></div></p>').appendTo(test);
  i++;
 });

// $(this).closest("p").remove();


 // $('.remtest').on('click', function() {
 //  if (i > 2) {
 //   $(this).parents('p').remove();
  //     i--;
 //  }
 // });
 $('body').on('click', '.remtest', function(e) {
  if (i > 2) {
   $(this).closest('.input-file-container').remove();
   i--;
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="p_test">
 <p>
  <div class="input-file-container">
   <input class="input-file" id="my-file" type="file">
   <label tabindex="0" for="my-file" class="input-file-trigger">Select a file...</label>
  </div>
  <p class="file-return"></p>
 </p>
</div>

<button class="btn--add" id="addtest">
        Add
</button>
```

Comment: This might solve the problem but nesting `div` and others in `p` is bad HTML.

Answer (score 0):

At first, just do not use jquery.
The second thing is that plain javascript is not hard and easy to use.
Therefore you can find how to do the things you want with javascript on the internet.

```js
function GetId(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

const button = GetId("addtest");
button.addEventListener("click", Add);
var id = 0;

function Add() {
  files.innerHTML = files.innerHTML + 
`<div id="`+ id +`">
  <br>
  <div class="input-file-container">
    <label for="p_test" class="input-file-trigger">
      Select a file...
      <input type="text" id="p_test" name="p_test_" value=""class="input-file">
    </label>
    <p class="file-return">
    </p>
    <button class="remtest" onclick="Remove('`+ id +`')">
      Remove
    </button>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>`;
id++;
}

function Remove(id) {
  const files = GetId("files")
  files.removeChild(GetId(id));
}
```

```html
<div id="p_test">
  <div>
    <div class="input-file-container">
      <input class="input-file" id="my-file" type="file">
      <label tabindex="0" for="my-file" class="input-file-trigger">Select a file...</label>
      </div>
    <div class="file-return" id="files"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn--add" id="addtest">Add</button>
```